# TextView returns NPE in for dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a method to show dialog and it contains a textview inside it. So I am trying to call that textview to set its text like`tvD.setText("SELECT")`. But for some reason the app is giving me NPE. Here is my code

This is prompts.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvD"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="PICK"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

And this is the method alertDialog

```
public void alertDialog() {
    final Context context = this;

    // get prompts.xml view
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
    final TextView tvDialog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvD);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);
    // set prompts.xml to alertDialog builder
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
    // set its text
    tvDialog.setText("HELLO");
    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Why am I getting this NPE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
final TextView tvDialog = (TextView)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.tvD);
```

`TextView` belongs to the inflated layout. `findViewById` looks for a view in the current infalted layout. So you need to use the view object to initialie `TextView`.

Comment: Thanks got it. Will accept the answer in 10 minutes as for some reason it is showing me I cant accept now.

Comment: I have put the whole alertDialog method in a new class and it is showing me an error for 'this' on 'final Conext context=this'.

Comment: @VyprNoch where is this alertdialog code. inside onClick of a button?. is it in Activity?? or fragment??

Comment: Inside a button. And since many activities may require this I thought putting it in a new class and calling new objects and setting text would be good. It was in the activity but then I created a class that doesnt extend anything. If I use extends Activity then I have to put onCreate method and I am not sure how to handle multiple calls to same code in onCreate

Comment: @VyprNoch use `ActivityName.this`. If its in a non activity class you need the context pass to the contructor of the class. then you can use it there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49260/discussion-between-vyprnoch-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 2):

You are finding the TextView from the wrong place, do it as follows:

```
 // get prompts.xml view
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
final TextView tvDialog = (TextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.tvD);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

You have to use the inflated view to find the correct dialog's TextView.